# How find out function argument is empty

Tags: python

I want to make a function same range() for example func_range() that has three arguments for it 
func_range(start , end , step ) but when recall the function without parameter I want to print for example  "please set the argument " .

how could I check the existence of argument in function

```
func_range(5) :     print 1 to 5 
func_range(1 , 5) : print 1 to 5
func_range() : print "please set the argument"
```

Comment: You can also use default argument values instead of variable function arguments here. Note that instead of printing that error message, incorrect usages should throw an exception, so it’s best not to change the default behavior here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either give default values to parameters or you can args keyword

```
def func_range(*args):
    if not args:
         print('Please set the argument')

    start, end = args
```

Comment: by this method ( one arguments ) How can I use another start , end and stop parameter in this function

Comment: You can use args as I mentioned I have updated in my answer or you can use kwargs

Comment: I like use your solution about arg but the end line don't work ! (start, end = args ) if possible write the complete function for me . How find out in function the user enter one or two or three arguments and if user enter more than 3 argument print error message . if user enter one argument consider it as end and count 1 to end by 1 step and if enter 2 argument consider start and end by step=1 and if enter start , end and step count to start to stop by step parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional arguments like this:

```
>>> def f(start=None, end=None, step=None):
...     if (start == None and end == None and step == None):
...             print("please set the argument")
...     else:
...             pass #do whatever you wish
... 
>>> f()
please set the argument
```

Comment: How find out in function the user enter one or two or three arguments and if user enter more than 3 argument print error message . if user enter one argument consider it as end and count start to end by 1 step and if enter 2 argument consider start and end by step 1 and if enter start , end and step count to start to stop by step parameter